# group result using date from object keys and only get count the results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I'm having a hard time getting this complex return using MongoDB nor Javascript. Hope can anyone teach me how to get this return.

**Admin**.

group result by id

**user**
flatten result

Here's the data example.

```
let user = [
    {
  _id: 123,
  name: 'John',
  createdAt: "2015-08-12T00:00:00Z"
  },
  {
  _id: 124,
  name: 'Jane',
  createdAt: "2015-09-12T00:00:00Z"
  },
  {
  _id: 125,
  name: 'Robert',
  createdAt: "2015-09-12T00:00:00Z"
  },
  {
  _id: 126,
  name: 'Samson',
  createdAt: "2016-11-12T00:00:00Z"
  }
]
```

Expected Result

**user**

```
[
{
 "15-8": 1 //yyyy-mm: number of data for the month of august
},
{
 "15-9": 2
},
{
 "16-11": 1
}
]
```

**admin**

```
[
    {
     "15-8": 
   {
    _id: 123,
    count: 1
   }
    },
    {
     "15-9": {
     _id: 124,
     count: 1,
   },{
     _id: 125,
     count: 1
    },
    {
     "16-11": {
     _id: 126,
     count: 1
     }
    }
    ]
```

Comment: Where the `"16-11": 1` come from?

Comment: I edit the result after noticing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should have the function to get `key` from date string named `getKeyFromDate` with format result `YY-MM`
2. Loop `user` data to aggregate your data by using `reduce`, for example.

```js
let user = [
    {
      _id: 123,
      name: 'John',
      createdAt: "2015-08-12T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
      _id: 124,
      name: 'Jane',
      createdAt: "2015-09-12T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
      _id: 125,
      name: 'Robert',
      createdAt: "2015-09-12T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
      _id: 126,
      name: 'Samson',
      createdAt: "2016-11-12T00:00:00Z"
    }
];

const getKeyFromDate = (dateString) => {
  var date = new Date(dateString);
  var year = date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 3);
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  return `${year}-${month}`; // YY-MM
};

var result = user.reduce((acc, {createdAt}) => {
  var key = getKeyFromDate(createdAt);
  acc[key] = acc[key] || {[key]: 0}; //Also use shortcut like: acc[key] ??= {[key]: 0};
  acc[key][key] += 1;
  return acc; 
  
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

**You can also use `for..of` if you're not familiar with `.reduce`**

```
var result2 = {};
for(let {createdAt} of user){
  var key = getKeyFromDate(createdAt);
  result2[key] = result2[key] || {[key]: 0};
  result2[key][key] += 1;
}
console.log(Object.values(result2));
```

Comment: I'm getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

Comment: That is the logical nullish assignment operator `??=` which isn't fully supported yet, use `acc[key] = acc[key] || {[key]: 0};` for compatibility.

Comment: @pilchard you're right. the shortcut `??=` named  [Logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

Comment: now its getting null. Is it okay if you can explain to me the code you've provided so that I know how it works

Comment: I'm getting this result

    "2021-1": {
                "2021-1": 9
            },
            "2021-2": {
                "2021-2": 1
            }
        }

Comment: Note this line code `Object.values(result)`

Comment: Thank you. Do I also need to use reduce if I want to also group the results by Id?

Comment: No, you can also use `for...of`, `forEach` to loop. the `.reduce` just ES6 feature with nicer code.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, pls take a look at @rainier-albario

Comment: yup. I saw it bro